# OpenID-Connect, Google+ iOS SDK, no browser

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-openid

It seems this used to be possible, but not anymore. Here's my dilemma: I'm creating an iPad educational software app, and I want to let students log in with their Google Apps for Education accounts using OpenID-Connect.

... I guess my first question is: is the current Google+ SDK the right way to perform login against GAFE? What about the forthcoming "Google Classroom"?

So say I do this - the student pushes the "login with google button", the sdk performs an app switch to safari and lets the user log in to their google account, push the permissioning buttons, and app-switches back to my app, and the user is now logged in. Fine. At the end of the class period, the user logs out of my app and hands in their device. The next period, though, another student logs in, and because the first user has forgotten to also log out of google in safari, the second user has access to their account.

... My second question is: is this a valid concern? Seems like this would be a pretty common usage pattern.

... Third question - can I get around this? Can I make Google+ sdk use an internal UIWebView, or no web stuff at all? This is what seems like used to be possible, but no longer...

EDIT: Spoke to google tech support for apps-for-enterprise (thx M!) and they say that there is no way to authenticate against google openid-connect without going through a browser. This is, I believe, a security problem - students being kids, they will forget to log out of the browser, and the next kids will get into mischief. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GPPSignin` class describes itself as:

> It provides single sign-on via the Google+ app (if installed), Chrome
>   for iOS (if installed), or Mobile Safari.

Internal web views are not mentioned. You may need to implement OAuth2.0 on your own to allow your internal UIWebView to manage authorization.

Google publishes an API which includes a method to `signOut`. You can use it at your app's discretion in addition to the SDK requirement that a user be able to sign out manually.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in